# What does "ci" in "utf8_general_ci" stand for

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

Short question:

**What does the "ci" in "utf8_general_ci" mean / stand for?**

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It means `case insensitive`. That way you don't have to worry about the case of letters in comparision for instance.

```
select 'A' = 'a'
```

returns true for case insensitive databases.

Comment: Is `utf8_bin` a case-sensitive counterpart?

Comment: Yes, BUT not only - it compares the strings' binary representation. So it is not only case sensitive, but "anything sensitive" - accents, combined characters (both u¨ and ü ends up as ü when interpreted),...

Answer (score -2):

utf8_general_ci is generally used for case insensitive character recognition. It means you can check the condition or get data from the database without CASE matter.

Example:

```
select Name from student where 'R' = 'r';
```

Comment: Why do you post an answer which is the same as the one that has been posted half a year earlier...